# Why are my files not uploaded to Opera Mini?

Tags: javascript, php, post, file-upload, opera-mini

I am working on a web-page, which works nicely in most browsers, but not in Opera Mini. Unfortunately I have issues with uploading a file. I have been trying to solve it for hours. I have this javascript:

```
                $("body").append('<form id="opera-mini-uploader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="hiddenValues" id="hidden-values" value=""><input type="file" name="src"><input type="submit" id="upload-opera-mini" name="upload-opera-mini" value="upload"></form>');
                $("#opera-mini-uploader").submit(function() {
                    $("#hidden-values").val(JSON.stringify({
                        "product-title": $("#product-title").val(),
                        "product-description": $("#product-description").val(),
                        "category-id": $("#category-id").val(),
                        "product-price": $("#product-price").val(),
                        "varsity": $("#varsity").val(),
                        "campus-of-varsity": $("#campus-of-varsity").val(),
                        "telephone": $("#telephone").val(),
                        "repeat-telephone": $("#repeat-telephone").val(),
                        "iagree": $("#iagree").prop("checked")
                    }));
                });
```

It creates a form with a file input and handles the submit to save other properties on file upload. The properties are saved nicely, but the file is not uploaded... The form appears at the end of the body, when I select a file and try to upload it, it is not successful. I do not see errors, but the file is not uploaded either. My question is: what I am doing the wrong way? How should I implement the file upload to actually have some files on the server? The file upload works for other browsers, but here I have created a separate version for that, because Opera Mini is not able to comply to the fancy features.

Comment: Is your PHP file's `$_FILE` empty?

Comment: I have an if-else, using flourishlib's fRequest::isPost(). If that is true, I am checking the $_FILE and if it has a "src" element, then the image is processed. It works wonderfully for other browsers, but for Opera Mini it is not even getting there, however, I know the post was successful, because my saved values are re-entered and automatically validated after I click the upload button.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of experimenting, I have found out the answer:

```
$("body").append('<form id="opera-mini-uploader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="hiddenValues" id="hidden-values" value=""><input type="file" name="src"><input type="submit" id="upload-opera-mini" name="upload-opera-mini" value="upload"></form>');
```

The code above creates the `form`, but the `submit` event will not be bound to it. Instead of this generation I have decided to test it by adding it as HTML, like this:

```
<form id="opera-mini-uploader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="hiddenValues" id="hidden-values" value=""><input type="file" name="src"><input type="submit" id="upload-opera-mini" name="upload-opera-mini" value="upload"></form>
```

and it worked like a charm without additional changes.